# Flutter theme - primarySwatch vs primaryColor

Tags: flutter

When defining theme data, what should I use - primarySwatch or primaryColor?

Can they be used together?

And finaly, what's the difference between them?

```
ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: kBaseColor,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: kBaseColor,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
),
```

Answer (score 3):

`primaryColor` has a type `Color` with *shade[500]* of `primarySwatch`, that itself has type `MaterialColor`.

Preferable to use `primarySwatch` to let app define different shades for its components.

This is a code fragment how theme colors are defined in [theme_data.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d79295af24/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart#L218) (material library):

```dart
    final Brightness _brightness = brightness ?? colorScheme?.brightness ?? Brightness.light;
    final bool isDark = _brightness == Brightness.dark;

    primaryColor ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[900]! : primarySwatch;
    primaryColorLight ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[500] : primarySwatch[100]!
    toggleableActiveColor ??= isDark ? Colors.tealAccent[200]! : (accentColor ?? primarySwatch[600]!);
    secondaryHeaderColor ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[700]! : primarySwatch[50]!;
    textSelectionHandleColor ??= isDark ? Colors.tealAccent[400]! : primarySwatch[300]!;
```

and so on.